# Silverlight combobox selectedvalue string property binding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, combobox

I have a combobox with items like below:

```
{[1, US]}
{[2, UK]}
```

My combobox will display it with the `Value`. My problem is I can't set the `SelectedValue` property of my combobox.

```
<ComboBox Name="cbSource" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
ItemsSource="{Binding Datas.Countries, Mode=OneWay}" 
SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentObject.Country, Mode=TwoWay}"     
DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key"></ComboBox>
```

Now my `CurrentObject.Country` is a string property with a value of `UK`. I also tried this one below but no luck.

```
DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Value"
```

What can I do here?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to ask here. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve your behavior using a key value pair. See the example below.
Just create a class having 2 properties one for key and one for value. Then bind a collection of this class as the itemssource and bind the selectedvalue to a string property. Ie Datas.Countries is the collection of the class.

```
<ComboBox Name="cbSource" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
ItemsSource="{Binding Datas.Countries, Mode=OneWay}" 
SelectedValue="{Binding SomePropertyToHoldKeyValue, Mode=TwoWay}"     
DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key"></ComboBox>
```

**I think we can understand the difference between SelectedItem, SelectedValue, DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath better with an example. See this class:**

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
}
```

and the following xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employees}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

`DisplayMemberPath` points to the Name property, so the value displayed in the ComboBox and the Employee entries contained in the drop down list, will be the Name property of the Employee object.

To understand the other two, you should first understand `SelectedItem`. `SelectedItem` will return the currently selected Employee object from the ComboBox. You can also assign `SelectedItem` with an Employee object to set the current selection in the ComboBox.

`SelectedValuePath` points to Id, which means you can get the Id of currently selected Employee by using `SelectedValue`. You can also set the currently selected Employee in the ComboBox by setting the `SelectedValue` to an Id (which we assume will be present in the Employees list).